# Turn Off Liferay RTL feature

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, portlet

is there any way to turn off the liferay RTL (Right To Left) feature that is used when viewing pages in farsi or hebrew ?

We had some complaints because of the mirroring - feature but still want to display the page in farsi / hebrew ...

Thanks a lot !

Daniel

p.s. posted the same question in the liferay message board here:

https://web.liferay.com/de/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/85920728

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found the answer:

You can turn off RTL / LTR Feature in the Language properties for the language that you want to change.

Here is what you need to add to the file Language_fa.properties:

```
lang.dir=ltr
lang.line.begin=left
lang.line.end=right
```